# Multiple addn-hosts conf in DNSMasq

Tags: linux, dnsmasq

Is it possible to add multiple files to the "addn-hosts" node in dnsmasq.conf?

Currently I have a single file "dnsmasq.multihosts" which has a list of servers for DNSmasq to resolve. My problem is that dnsmasq.multihosts is too long now and I would like to separate it into multiple Files like  "dnsmasq.database", "dnsmasq.webserver" etc for easy maintenance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to specify multiple files for `--addn-hosts` in `dnsmasq.conf`. This option may be repeated for more than one additional hosts file. If a directory is given, all the files in that directory will be read.

```
dnsmasq --help
...
-H, --addn-hosts=<file>    Additional hosts file. Read the specified file as well as
                           /etc/hosts. If -h is given, read only the specified file.
                           This option may be repeated for more than one additional
                           hosts file. If a directory is given, then read all the files
                           contained in that directory.
```

The `dnsmasq` manual page is at http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html.

Comment: @AnkitGupta Upvote and accept my answer if you think it is useful so that others know this is the right answer, thanks!